# Multiple node instances, NGINX reverse proxy, serves page, 404 error on post requests?

Tags: node.js, reverse-proxy, digital-ocean, nginx-config

So my stack is running on a Digital Ocean droplet. Initial node.js application is served at https://domain_name.com/. The requests are processed through NGINX reverse proxy to port 3000.

I now have a second application running on port 3001; both instances are running in PM2. 
The second application is reached by way of https://domain_name.com/cards/.

When this address is accessed it delivers the first page as expected. However when a POST request is placed. to address https://domain_name.com/cards/api_route/. Console in the browser displays a 404 error. This, however, functions perfectly on Localhost node instance.

My sites-enabled 'default' file contains the following location blocks.

```
HTTPS â€” proxy all requests to the Node app

server {
     # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name domain_name.com;
    # Use the Letâ€™s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_name.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_name.com/privkey.pem;
    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

 location /card {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
      proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }


  location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
      proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_redirect off;
      }
  }
```

Paths are however correct to api routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved....

The location block

location /card {

needed to be

location /card/ {

Previously searching https://domain_name.com/cards

delivered the page and:

https://domain_name.com/cards/

Returned error: CANNOT GET //